# Trace zero matrix that can't be written as $AB - BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, examples-counterexamples

According to [this paper](http://faculty.plattsburgh.edu/robert.reams/research/intmatrx.pdf), every trace zero matrix over a field can be written in the form $AB - BA$.  However, here's a basic counterexample:

Let $A = diag(a, -a)$ for some nonzero number a.  Then $A  = BC - CB$ if and only if a system of equations involving entries of $B,C,A$ is true.  Then the entries of $A$ are:

$$\begin{align}
a = b_{1,1}c_{1,1} + b_{1,2}c_{2,1} - b_{1,1}c_{1,1} - b_{2,1}c_{1,2} \\
0 = b_{1,1}c_{1,2} + b_{1,2}c_{2,2} - b_{1,1}c_{2,1} - b_{2,1}c_{2,2} \\
-a = b_{2,1}c_{1,1} + b_{2,2}c_{2,1} - b_{1,2}c_{1,1} - b_{2,2}c_{1,2} \\
0 = b_{2,1}c_{1,2} + b_{2,2}c_{2,2} - b_{1,2}c_{2,1} - b_{2,2}c_{2,2}
\end{align}
$$

For $a$ nonzero the first and the last equations can't both be true.  So where did I mess up?

Comment: qaphla, how did you do that so fast?

Comment: Lots of practice with LaTeX and I type about 85-90wpm.

Comment: I believe you want to interchange -a and 0 in the last two equations.

Comment: @user84413.  And there it is!  Thanks!

Comment: For reference: I think this open access 1957 paper of [Albert and Muckenhoupt](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?verb=Display&version=1.0&service=UI&handle=euclid.mmj/1028990168&page=record) was the first published proof of this fact for a general field of any characteristic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ a & 0 \end{bmatrix} -\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ a & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

What made you conclude that the first and last of those equations can't be true?

Comment: I made a mistake, writing them down on paper.  But qaphla corrected it.  Two LHS's were swapped.

Answer (score 5):

$$B=\left(\begin{array}{rr}0&1\\0&0\end{array}\right).$$
$$C=a\left(\begin{array}{rr}0&0\\1&0\end{array}\right).$$
$$BC-CB=\left(\begin{array}{rr}a&0\\0&-a\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: Why does your avatar say community wiki and have no rating?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Comment: Citing Henning: "Credit waived". I use it occasionally. This time partly because I didn't address your question, i.e. I didn't help you spotting the mistake.